# Using Tkinter, How can I make a button to open or choose a file?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently using Tkinter to "polish up" my encoding and decoding files into DNA project. I have never used, frankly any GUI before. If anyone here could help me with this it would be much appreciated! Thank you! I am not sure though if I have to upload the files to the GUI or no.

Comment: I don't think so. I am new here and I don't want to copy anybody who was already here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filedialog` of `tkinter`, demo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print('Selected:', filename)

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=UploadAction)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

*Note: also prints the file that is selected.*

Answer (score 0):

To open a file try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

#if you want additional options:
import tkinter.simpledialog
window = tk.Tk()
window.withdraw() #hides the window
file = tk.simpledialog.askstring("file", "Options Here")
```